# Send a POST request in jQuery when a div is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the following done.

- click on a paragraph element
- send a .post request using jQuery
- get the sent data from the server to display in the paragraph

I've searched quite a bit and tried using some of the solutions proposed but it failed.

Here's my folder structure:

```
+ html
    - index.html
+ js
    - eventhandling.js
+ php
    - test.php
```

HTML

```
<div class="channel" id="channel1">
    <p class="title">CHANNEL 01</p>
    <p class="stb_sub_menu" id="model">STB Model</p>
    <p class="network_sub_menu" id="network">Network</p>
    <p class="smartcard_sub_menu" id="smartcard">Smartcard</p>
    <p id="reboots">Reboots</p>
</div>
<p id="demodata">Demo Data</p>
```

PHP

```
<?php echo "PHP script -> You called master?"; ?>
```

JS

```
$(".channel").click(function(){
    /*alert(I am clicked");*/
    $.post('test.php', {name: 'John'}, function(data) {
        $("#demodata").val("data");
    });
});
```

The click event is successful because the alert pops up. Nothing shows on the Firebug console window.

Comment: Literally nothing happens in the console?

Comment: Try $("#demodata").html(data);

Comment: @next2u It's ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: @WesleyMurch But he is using val() method instead of html(). And P tag don't have a value attribute.

Comment: @JayBhatt That's it. Still should be a request in the console thought.

Comment: @WesleyMurch He's not logging anything to console. And most browsers will allow this.

Comment: @JayBhatt Ah does Firefox require you to open another panel to show ajax requests or something? I guess that makes sense, maybe he didn't know where to look. The requests are shown by default in Chrome.

Comment: use .html() or .text() instead of .val();

Comment: @WesleyMurch Not sure about Firefox but in Chrome you need developer tools open. And sometimes it doesn't work so need to reload the page.

Comment: @WesleyMurch That's right. nothing happens at all. There's no debug in the console that says that  the post request went through.

Comment: @JayBhatt sorry man, i didn't know that <p> did not have a val attribute. But changing it to html ot text did not work as well

Answer (score 1):

Might be the service URL you passed into post is wrong (according to the folder structure).
The code must be like this.

```
$(".channel").click(function(){
    var postData = {"name":"john"};
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '../php/test.php',
        data: postData ,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json", 
        processdata: true,
        success: function (response) {

        },
        error: function(error){
        }
      });
   });
```

This will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".channel").click(function(){
    /*alert(I am clicked");*/
    $.post('test.php', {name: 'John'}, function(data) {
        $("#demodata").text(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: @WesleyMurch It's a variable. "data" would set the text to literal string 'data' always.

Comment: Right, which should work and print "data" in the div, the part I missed was OP used `val()`.